# Upgrade AWS ec2 ebs instance to a reserved instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, snapshot, updating

Just upgraded and have no idea how to migrate my existing m1.small instance to a reserved m3.medium instance.

I upgraded because my server was running slow. Would it be possible to give me a step by step on how to migrate my original instance over to the reserved one?

I'm using the ec2 dashboard. From what I've read I create a snapshot, but that's how far I've got. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **Reserved Instance** on Amazon EC2 is a means of reducing the hourly cost of using EC2. In exchange for an up-front payment, the hourly charge for EC2 is reduced.

**A Reserved Instance has several components:**

- Instance type (the size of EC2 instance, consisting of an family, CPU count and RAM size)
- Operating System (eg costs vary for Windows vs Linux)
- Availability Zone (used to ensure that capacity has been allocated)

Each hour, the AWS billing system looks for any running instances in an account that owns Reserved Instances. If any of the running instances match the above three attributes, then the instance will **receive the pricing discount**. (Only one instance will receive a discount per Reserved Instance per 'running' hour.)

**It is not possible to select a specific Amazon EC2 instance and designate it as a Reserved Instance.** The billing system does this automatically. Thus, an instance could be discounted one hour and not another hour, depending upon what other instances are running. Think of it as a billing discount rather than a particular instance being "the" Reserved Instance.

Reserved Instances are also **shared across AWS Accounts** that are connected via [consolidated billing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/consolidated-billing.html). If there is no matching instance to receive a discount in the AWS Account that owns the Reserved Instance, the billing system will attempt to allocate it to a matching running instance in a linked AWS Account for that hour.

Therefore, to make use of your new m3.medium Reserved Instance via the AWS management console:

- **Stop** your existing `m1.small` instance
- From the Actions menu, select **Instance Settings** / **Change Instance Type**
- Select `m3.medium`
- **Start** your instance

Make sure that your instance matches the Instance Type, Availability Zone and Operating System listed in your Reserved Instance and you will automatically receive the billing discount. If multiple running EC2 instances match the profile of the Reserved Instance, only one will receive the discount.

There is **no need to create an EBS snapshot** or create a new instance. Simply changing the instance attributes to match the Reserved Instance is sufficient.

Note: **The Reserved Instance itself will not provide any speed improvement.** It is just a billing discount. It is your choice of a larger instance type will provide the benefit.

See also:

- [Reserved Instance documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts-on-demand-reserved-instances.html)
- [Resizing your instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html)